# Why does <li class="default-menu"> appear? I'm trying to remove a generic link called navigation on my main menu

Tags: menus, front-end, user-interface

I really didn't know where else to turn to.  It really seems like major overkill to have to manually set class=default-menu to display:none and twice as much ditto to build a filter on functions.php just to remove a default navigation button.  Is there a way to do this or configure this setting within the wordpress settings?

[image]

Nothing I've found in the menu options or online seems to point to an easy explanation nor solution of what that is and how to remove it.  I thought it was a theme issue so I looked for theme options - none.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What default navigation button?

Comment: Ok so look at the screenshot there - see that button on the far right that says navigation - it shouldn't be there!  I opened the chrome dev tools to show that it assigns a class 'default-menu', but I have not set this button at all and it does not appear when I disable 'set as primary menu' checkbox on the menu settings page in admin.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not Core. Did you write this theme yourself?